# Linear Algebra Practice Midterm Question: vectors in span

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, solution-verification

Let $u_1, ..., u_m$ be vectors in **span**$\{v_1,...,v_k\}$; and let $\{v_1,...v_k\}$ be vectors in **span**$\{w_1,...,w_n\}$. Show that $u_1, ..., u_m$ are vectors in **span**$\{w_1,...,w_n\}.$

I am not sure how to prove this using appropriate formulas and theorems. Conceptually I understand that if the $u$ vectors are in the span of the $v$ vectors, and if the $v$ vectors are in the span of the $w$ vectors, then the $u$ vectors must be in the span of the $w$ vectors. I just don't know how to properly prove it.

Comment: What does it mean for $u$ to be in the span of $\{v_1,v_2\}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument, by itself, is relatively straightforward.

If $u_1,\ldots,u_m$ belong to $span(v_1,\ldots,v_k)$, then each of those vectors can be expressed as some linear combination of the vectors in $\{v_1,\ldots,v_k\}$. Remember, there is an underlying field $\mathbb{F}$ and an underlying vector space $(V,+,\cdot)$ that we need to keep in mind.

Now, since the vectors $\{v_1,\ldots,v_k\}$ belong to $span(w_1,\ldots,w_n)$ each vector in the set $\{v_1,\ldots,v_k\}$ can be expressed as some linear combination of the vectors in $\{w_1,\ldots,w_n\}$. So, it follows (using the algebraic rules on vector spaces) that every vector $u_1,\ldots,u_m$ can be expressed as a linear combination of the vectors $\{w_1,\ldots,w_n\}$. This is exactly what we wanted.

I would say that, for most people, this would be enough. Like, you can definitely formalize the above and I'd say that if you're not too experienced with Mathematics, then you probably should try to formalize it. I just hope that the gist of the argument is clear, though.